# Monaca CLI 6.2 - Create/Edit build-extras.gradle

Tags: android, cordova, build.gradle, phonegap-cli, monaca

Having a hard time configuring Monaca IDE with PhoneGap/Cordova 6.2 CLI, specifically with adding a build-extras.gradle file to the Android side of the project. Seems Monaca took away a lot of abilities to customize an application. Does anyone know how to override that so I can add a build-extras.gradle?

Here is my directory structure for my project. Note that Chrome is the only platform I can get to:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: did you try to put the file in `res/android` dir? Monaca changed platform structure since 6.2 release

Comment: Andi - I just updated my question with a screen shot. Are you saying that if I add the build-extras.gradle to the res/android folder in my screenshot, that will work?